# Python regex all letters a-zA-Z except letter f?

Tags: python, regex

In the python regex below I need to ignore the letter 'f':

[a-zA-Z] I don't want the 'f' in that regex.

is it possible to do that?

https://pythex.org/

test string:

> MDCore.poster="//s-delivery15.mxdcontent.net/thumbs/2a9eb51ea746cf322c83cf60b5ac3acd.jpg";MDCore.furl="
>   ";MDCore.wurl="//s-delivery15.mxdcontent.net/v/2a9eb51ea746cf322c83cf60b5ac3acd?s=alp2UW7dP-gmVGa-ACoERA&e=1579990634";MDCore.vfile="2a9eb51ea746cf322c83cf60b5

I need the same result generated by this expression, but here I started from the letter 'g' to ignore the letter 'f':

```
(?:vsr|[g-zG-Z]url)[^=]*=\s*"([^"]+)
```

I need something like this but ignoring the letter 'f' in "[a-zA-Z]url":

```
(?:vsr|[a-zA-Z]url)[^=]*=\s*"([^"]+)
```

Comment: Just use [a-eg-zA-EG-Z]

Comment: Thank you solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work

```
(?:vsr|[a-eg-zA-EG-Z]url)[^=]*=\s*"([^"]+)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```py
re.compile("[a-eg-z]",flags=re.I)
```

It will match all the letters from `"a"` to `"e"` and from `"g"` to `"z"` and the flag `re.I` will have it ignore case.

Comment: Thank you solved my problem!

Comment: Sure, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the **wurl**, you can use a group:

```py
re.compile(r'MDCore\.wurl=\"(.[^\"]+)')
```

See the [link to regex](https://regex101.com/r/1jrt8m/2)

All other answers I saw will also remove the '**f**' in the URL and that can't be right.